# Why is Python able to read CSV only in the "Downloads" folder and not in other folders on my PC?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file in python via Pandas, however I found that I can only read the file if it is in the "Downloads" folder, if the file is in any other folder the error appears [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'c:/Users/Adones/Desktop/Projetos_Python/intro_bees.csv')**
```

Shows the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/Users/Adones/Desktop/Projetos_Python/intro_bees.csv'**
```

But if I put de way

```py
data = pd.read_csv(r'c:/Users/Adones/Downloads/intro_bees.csv')
```

it works normally

Does anyone konw why this happen?

Comment: We can't see files on your desktop, so not sure we can answer this, but either Projetos_Python folder doesn't exist, or the file doesn't, or you have some file permissions restricting access to the file when it's not in the downloads folder

Comment: are you absolutely sure the file exists in both place? can `pathlib` see the files?

Comment: Also what are those asterisks in first two snippets?